# Service worker registration via 3rd party

Tags: javascript, service-worker, web-push

Service workers can only be installed on a HTTPS domain. However, i have seen products where companies are hosting service worker and manifest.json on their https domain  and able to register it on http domains.

Example - http://www.site1.com can register service-worker from https://cdn.site2.com.

Can anyone explain how its done?

Comment: can you provide examples for such sites ?

Comment: https://documentation.onesignal.com/v2.0/docs/website-sdk-http-installation

Answer (score 0):

Essentially here's how they do it:

1. As you said, `they host a service worker and manifest.json on their HTTPS domain` (usually on a subdomain that you choose when registering).
2. `You install their JavaScript client library on your website`, and in case your website is not HTTPS enabled, they use a workaround to subscribe visitors for push notifications, since web push notifications are only supported for HTTPS enabled websites.
3. They basically create an intermediate dialog that asks your visitors to subscribe. When they click on it, `a pop-up window is opened to the HTTPS enabled subdomain` that you chose earlier. So, now the browser will be able to ask permission and securely subscribe the visitor on their domain.

After that, you will be sending all the notifications using their website or APIs and all the notifications will be sent from their subdomain, as the origin, visible underneath, will show their HTTPS domain instead of your HTTP website URL.